# System.ComponentModel - ignore property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm creating custom UserControl in ASP.NET and I'm using System.ComponentModel.Attributes to decorate properties with different things. By default, ASP.NET shows all public GET; SET properties of a control in properties window on ASPX page. What attribute I can use to ignore some of the properties ?

I tried to find something related to "ignore" on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.aspx page, but didn't find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need [BrowsableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx)

> Specifies whether a property or event should be displayed in a
>   Properties window.

```
[Browsable(false)]
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to hide the property with [`[Browsable]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx) attribute.

> Specifies whether a property or event should be displayed in a
>   Properties window.